# Where are the "old" restricted drivers for dvb-t cards?

Tags: drivers, dvb, restricted, dvb-t

Another issue with Ubuntu 12.10: I have an USB DVB Avermedia card In 12.04, and all previous versions I remember since 10.x worked with this hardware enabling its driver in "restricted drivers".

Now I discovered that I cannot even enable the card, any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try going to update manager -> setting -> last tab on top..

Most probably you will find what you are looking for, there..